# Relacionamento SQL

Tags: relacionamento

Boa noite, estou criando um pequeno sistema no qual terei um formulário para Atendimento, onde o usuário irá selecionar um Cliente, e haverá um checkbox para multipla escolha para Serviços.

Alguém pode me dizer se minha linha de pensamento está correta?

Tabelas:
*Cliente
idCliente
nomeCliente
...

*Servico
idServico
descricao
valorServico

*Atendimento
idAtendimento
dataAtendimento
valorTotal
idServico - N - servicos    
idCliente - 1 - cliente

- Atendimento_Servico
  idAtendimento_Servico
  idAtendimento
  idServico

Caso de uso:
Cadastrando um atendimento com um cliente e 3 servicos selecionados via checkbox:
atendimento    cliente          servico 
1                            1        1,2,3

atendimento   atendimento_servico     servico
1                            1,1                            1
1                            1,2                             2
1                            1,3                            3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa ter uma tabela relacional entre atendimento e serviço, já que o relacionamento entre atendimento e serviço é n-para-n.

Basicamente, ficaria algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E a tabela 'atendimento_has_servico'  não precisa ter um id próprio?

Comment: Há quem queira criar um ID, há quem não queira. Você pode querer criar uma chave composta que é a junção do `atendimento_id` e do `servico_id`, assim nunca haverá duplicatas.